# Why doesn't the font family change in my program?

Tags: java, oop, awt

Sorry for my bad english.
I did laboratory work at the university, which consisted of implementing a graphical interface using java.awt.
idk why, but when i try to change Font with my interface, it assignes to the label font, but it doen't change in the interface. However Font size and Font angle changes.

Maybe it's sth stupid but i really don't know why it doesn't work

Here is my code

Main.java

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        MainWindow.set_main_window();

    }
}
```

MainWindow.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainWindow {

    private static Frame main_window;
    private static int height;
    private static int width;
    private static Label label;

    MainWindow(){
        main_window = new Frame();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Width: ");
        width = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Height: ");
        height = sc.nextInt();
        main_window.setSize(width, height);
    }

    public static int getHeight(){
        return height;
    }

    public static int getWidth(){
        return width;
    }

    public static void setFont(Font font){
        label.setFont(font);
        main_window.repaint();
        //System.out.println("!!! "+font.getFontName());
        System.out.println(label.getFont().getFontName());
    }

    public static void set_main_window(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        ChooseFontPanel Panel2 = new ChooseFontPanel();
        TextPanel Panel = new TextPanel();
        //System.out.print("Type text: ");
        //String labelText = sc.next();
        label = new Label("123");
        label.setBounds(main_window.getWidth()/2,
                main_window.getHeight()/6*5,
                50,
                25);
        label.setFont(ChooseFontPanel.getFont());

        List[] ListArray = ChooseFontPanel.getFontPanel();
        for (List item: ListArray)
            main_window.add(item);

        TextField t = TextPanel.getTextInputField();

        main_window.add(t);
        main_window.add(label);
        main_window.setLayout(null);
        main_window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

ChooseFontPanel.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class ChooseFontPanel{
    private static String fontName = "Agency FB";
    private static int fontSize = 12;
    private static int fontAngle = 0;
    private static Font chosenFont = new Font(fontName,fontAngle,fontSize);
    private static List fontList;
    private static List fontTypeList;
    private static List fontSizeList;
    public static List[] getFontPanel(){
        return new List[] {fontList,fontTypeList,fontSizeList};
    }

    public static List getFontList(){
        return fontList;
    }
    public static List getFontTypeList(){
        return fontTypeList;
    }
    public static List getFontSizeList(){
        return fontSizeList;
    }
    public static Font getFont(){
        return chosenFont;
    }
    ChooseFontPanel() {

        fontList = new List(267,false);
        String fontArray[] =
                GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
        for(int i=0;i<fontArray.length;i++) fontList.add(fontArray[i]);


        fontList.setBounds(10,
                MainWindow.getHeight()/3,
                MainWindow.getWidth()/3,
                MainWindow.getHeight()/3
        );
        fontList.select(0);
        fontList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //System.out.print(fontName+"->");
                fontName = fontList.getSelectedItem();
                chosenFont = new Font(fontName,fontAngle,fontSize);
                MainWindow.setFont(chosenFont);

                //System.out.println(fontName);
                //System.out.println(chosenfont.getFontName());
            }
        });

        fontTypeList = new List(3,false);
        fontTypeList.add("Plain");
        fontTypeList.add("Bold");
        fontTypeList.add("Italic");
        fontTypeList.setBounds(MainWindow.getWidth()/3+10,
                MainWindow.getHeight()/3,
                MainWindow.getWidth()/3,
                MainWindow.getHeight()/3
        );
        fontTypeList.select(0);
        fontTypeList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //System.out.print(fontAngle+"->");
                fontAngle = fontTypeList.getSelectedIndex();
                chosenFont = new Font(fontName,fontAngle,fontSize);
                MainWindow.setFont(chosenFont);
                //System.out.println(fontAngle);

            }
        });

        fontSizeList = new List(40,false);
        for(int i=2;i<=80;i+=2){
            fontSizeList.add(String.valueOf(i));
        }
        fontSizeList.setBounds(MainWindow.getWidth()/3*2+10,
                MainWindow.getHeight()/3,
                MainWindow.getWidth()/3-15,
                MainWindow.getHeight()/3
        );
        fontSizeList.select(5);

        fontSizeList.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //System.out.println(fontSizeList.getSelectedItem());
                //System.out.print(fontSize+"->");
                fontSize = Integer.parseInt(fontSizeList.getSelectedItem());
                chosenFont = new Font(fontName,fontAngle,fontSize);
                MainWindow.setFont(chosenFont);
                //System.out.println(fontSize);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

P.S. I know this code is bad, sorry haha

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/258057/unable-to-change-font-in-java-awt-menubar implies there are some limitations in AWT with fonts, not sure if these have ever been fixed since later development were in Swing, which in turn has been replaced by JavaFX

Comment: oh... ok, thanks

Comment: Missing the **TextPanel** class.

Comment: it's in the program, didn't add it bc it's empty. forgot to comment some parts of code, sorry

Answer (score 0):

try this changes. this should update the font of the label in real-time when you select different fonts, font styles, or font sizes in your gui:

```
public static void setFont(Font font) {
    label.setFont(font);
    main_window.revalidate(); // Revalidate the container to apply changes
}
```

Comment: didn't help, still this problem